# Android Retrofit - How to implement my url?

Tags: android, android-studio

Using android retrofit, I'm having problems referring to my url.

Either of these are ok to use:

http://www.example.com/foo.asmx/dostuf

Or

http://www.example.com/foo.ashx?r=dostuff

The examples I've seen indicate:
http://www.example.com/post

What file is that processing?

So, how to I implement my url?

Thanks

Comment: Essentially you are asking how to get started with retrofit?

Comment: No. I'm asking how to put my url into retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("Your Url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();



    return retrofit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.
Here it is to help out others...

The BASE url goes here:

```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://www.example.com/").build();
```

The ENDPOINT url goes here:

```
   public interface retrofit_post1  {
   @POST("example.ashx?r=dostuff")
   Call<ResponseBody> update(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
   }
```

Comment: This is a POST HTTTP request. I recommend you take a look at how to send GET HTTP requests. The urls that you are going to use does not use POST all the time!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, a POST is exactly the job to be done. The android app is sending information to the server for work to be done and then send back a simply reply.